# Vue.js: Conditional class style binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-formatting

I have some data that is accessible via:

```
{{ content['term_goes_here'] }}
```

... and this evaluated to either `true` or `false`.  I'd like to add a class depending on the truthiness of the expression like so:

```
<i class="fa" v-bind:class="[{{content['cravings']}} ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline']"></i>
```

where `true` gives me the class `fa-checkbox-marked` and false would give me `fa-checkbox-blank-outline`.  The way I wrote it above gives me an error:

```
- invalid expression: v-bind:class="[{{content['cravings']}} ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline']"
```

**How should I write it to be able to conditionally determine the class?**

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use the [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

```
v-bind:class="{'fa-checkbox-marked': content['cravings'],  'fa-checkbox-blank-outline': !content['cravings']}"
```

When the object gets more complicated, extract it into a method.

```
v-bind:class="getClass()"

methods:{
    getClass(){
        return {
            'fa-checkbox-marked': this.content['cravings'],  
            'fa-checkbox-blank-outline': !this.content['cravings']}
    }
}
```

Finally, you could make this work for any content property like this.

```
v-bind:class="getClass('cravings')"

methods:{
  getClass(property){
    return {
      'fa-checkbox-marked': this.content[property],
      'fa-checkbox-blank-outline': !this.content[property]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I refactored to: `<i class="fa" :class="[{ 'fa-checkbox-marked': content['cravings'] }, 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline']"></i>`

Comment: @JeremyThomas I would go with either the array syntax or the object syntax, but not both probably.

Comment: yeah, i was a little surprised to see that mixed syntax in their docs. not a fan.

Comment: How can you trigger the class binding to update when the watched properties are coming from an external source, like a `vue-router` change? (ex: `this.$router.push('/homepage')` called elsewhere in another component)

Comment: @bigp I expect you could watch `$route` for changes and change your classes as needed. https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html

Answer (score 51):

```
<i class="fa" v-bind:class="cravings"></i>
```

and add in computed :

```
computed: {
    cravings: function() {
        return this.content['cravings'] ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline';
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have to have too many methods as there are about 20 different terms

Comment: Vote up for computed, its much cleaner than having expressions inside the html tags.

Answer (score 46):

Why not pass an object to v-bind:class to dynamically toggle the class:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ disabled: order.cancelled_at }"></div>
```

This is what is recommended by the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes).

Answer (score 13):

the problem is blade, try this

```
<i class="fa" v-bind:class="['{{content['cravings']}}' ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline']"></i>
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use string template like below with backticks `` :

```
:class="`${content['cravings'] ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline'}`"
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to apply separate css classes for same element with conditions in **Vue.js**
you can use the below given method.it worked in my scenario.

**html**

```
 <div class="Main" v-bind:class="{ Sub: page}"  >
```

in here, **Main** and **Sub** are two different class names for same div element.
**v-bind:class** directive is used to bind the sub class in here.
**page** is the property we use to update the classes when it's value changed.

**js**

```
data:{
page : true;
}
```

here we can apply a condition if we needed.
so, if the page property becomes true element will go with **Main** and **Sub** *claases css styles. but if false only **Main** class css styles will be applied.*

Comment: Most understandable answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple ways to do that. You can use the condition directly inside the v-bind like this:

```
<i v-bind:class="`${content['cravings'] ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline'}`">
```

And the other one is where you use the condition inside the script part, like this in the template:

```
<i v-bind:class="yourClass">
```

And then this in the script:

```
data() { 
    return { 
      yourClass = content['cravings'] ? 'fa-checkbox-marked' : 'fa-checkbox-blank-outline' 
    }
}
```