# VueJS dynamic class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Reading the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) I don't understand how I can change a class.

My component data looks like this:

```
props: [
  'm_c_id',
  'recipient_id',
  'sender_id',
  'userId'
],
```

Now if `sender_id == userId` I want to show this in my template:

```
<div class="msg-from-me">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

or if `recipient_id == userId` I want to show this:

```
<div class="msg-from-them">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is covered well in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Comment: @BertEvans is it like this? ``v-bind:class="{'msg-from-me': userId==m_sender_id, 'msg-from-them': userId==m_recipient_id}"``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js: Conditional class styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210508/vue-js-conditional-class-styling)

Comment: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the ternary operator to toggle classes:

```
<div v-bind:class="[sender_id === userId ? msg-from-me : msg-from-them]">
```

This way, if the only two options are sender_id or recipient_id, the proper class will toggle.